# Copy text from a text field and insert into another textarea at the current cursor position

Tags: javascript, razor-pages

ref the image below, when I click the add button, I need to copy the text from the first text field "Rule Prefix" and then using the clipboard, I then need to insert the copied text into the other `textarea` "EditedEvent" at the current cursor position.

Code below I believe is almost there but I can't seem to convert the the copied text into a format that allows it to be inserted into the other text area.

Once this is achieved then the next task is to do the reverse using the remove button and remove the copied text from the `textarea` "Edited Event".

Note the `textarea` "Edited Event" will be configured as read only so users cant edit it directly.

[image: screenshot]

```
 // Function Rule Prefix Add Button
function rulePrefixAdd() {

    /* Get the text field */
    var copyText = document.getElementById("rulePrefixInput");

    /* If text field is empty, show alert */
    if (copyText.value.length == 0) {
        /* Popup Window Alert the copied text */
        alert("Text input is empty!");
        return;
    }

    /* Select the text field */
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/

    /* Copy the text inside the text field */
    var textString = document.execCommand("copy");

    //alert('textString'); // Alert box contains the correct string

    // NOT WORKING - PLEASE HELP
    typeInTextarea($(editedEventTextArea), textString);

    // This works but I dont want a hardcoded string, need to insert the text from clipboard.
    //typeInTextarea($(editedEventTextArea), "  << LOOK WHAT I DID! >>  ")
}

 function typeInTextarea(el, newText) {
    var start = el.prop("selectionStart")
    var end = el.prop("selectionEnd")
    var text = el.val()
    var before = text.substring(0, start)
    var after = text.substring(end, text.length)
    el.val(before + newText + after)
    el[0].selectionStart = el[0].selectionEnd = start + newText.length
    el.focus()
    return false
}
```

Comment: (offtopic) rule prefix yet ended up in the middle of "SampleStringblahblahblah"... what are you building? How you even managed to select in the middle of a non-editable area?

Comment: And you managed to say: *"pasted at the current cursor position"* and *"the textarea is not editable"* in the same question...

Comment: So if it's true that the textarea is actually editable (not readonly) (hence one can put a caret into it) -  than what if the caret is right in the middle of a prefix rule and you want to add another one? Than how should the "Remove" thing work with nested *rules(?)*?

Comment: OK perhaps read only was the wrong terminology for web based apps, I had this all working in Windows Forms but trying to apply the same cause and affect to asp.net core with javascript is obviously a different kettle of fish. Dont read too much into the fact i called the text field Rule Prefix, I require the same logic for other form fields as well so just after the working solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized that the form-group attribute in the parent div class on the razor page was preventing the javascript function from inserting the text into the textarea. Ref comments above, i have removed the need to copy the text to the clipboard, updated function below seems to work OK.

```
 // Function Rule Prefix Add Button
function rulePrefixAdd() {

    /* Get the text field */
    var copyText = document.getElementById("rulePrefixInput");

    /* If text field is empty, show alert */
    if (copyText.value.length == 0) {
        /* Popup Window Alert the copied text */
        alert("Text input is empty!");
        return;
    }

    typeInTextarea($(editedEventTextArea), copyText.value);
}
```